# Parsing a file using text processing tools

Tags: text-processing

A file looks like:

```
1140.271257 0.002288454025 0.002763420728 0.004142512599 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1479.704769 0.00146621631 0.003190634646 0.003672029231 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1663.276205 0.003379552854 0.04643209167 0.0539399155 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Can I use some text processing tool to split it into two files such as:

1:

```
1140.271257 0.002288454025 0.002763420728 0.00414251259
1479.704769 0.00146621631 0.003190634646 0.003672029231
1663.276205 0.003379552854 0.04643209167 0.0539399155
```

2:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Just get the first numbers, which are not 0, and then just put the rest in another file... if the file could be named like the original file name with a x1 and x2 or so it would be cool.

Comment: The count of `0` in your input file in the last line doesn't match with the count of `0` in your output

Comment: Do the zeros always start at the 5th field?

Answer (score 6):

With `awk`. The command below checks every entry in every line and writes in different files, in my example `out1` and `out2`. If there is a newline in the input file, also a newline will be written in the output file.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if($i!=0) {printf "%s ",$i > "out1"} else {printf "%s ",$i > "out2"}; if (i==NF) {printf "\n" > "out1"; printf "\n" > "out2"} }}' foo
```

---

*Example*

The input file

`cat foo`

```
1140.271257 0.002288454025 0.002763420728 0.004142512599 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1479.704769 0.00146621631 0.003190634646 0.003672029231 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1663.276205 0.003379552854 0.04643209167 0.0539399155 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The command

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if($i!=0) {printf "%s ",$i > "out1"} else {printf "%s ",$i > "out2"}; if (i==NF) {printf "\n" > "out1"; printf "\n" > "out2"} }}' foo
```

The output files

`cat out1`

```
1140.271257 0.002288454025 0.002763420728 0.004142512599 
1479.704769 0.00146621631 0.003190634646 0.003672029231 
1663.276205 0.003379552854 0.04643209167 0.0539399155
```

`cat out2`

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: @terdon oh yes, right

Comment: @heineman: As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed use a text processing tool to do so, but if the purpose is to separate the first 4 fields from what is following them using `cut` is enough:

```
 cut -d ' ' -f 1-4 infile > outfile1
 cut -d ' ' -f 5- infile > outfile2
```

```
user@debian ~/tmp % cat infile
1140.271257 0.002288454025 0.002763420728 0.004142512599 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1479.704769 0.00146621631 0.003190634646 0.003672029231 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1663.276205 0.003379552854 0.04643209167 0.0539399155 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
user@debian ~/tmp % cut -d ' ' -f 1-4 infile
1140.271257 0.002288454025 0.002763420728 0.004142512599
1479.704769 0.00146621631 0.003190634646 0.003672029231
1663.276205 0.003379552854 0.04643209167 0.0539399155
user@debian ~/tmp % cut -d ' ' -f 5- infile 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: There's no need for all these quotes: `cut -d' ' -f5- file` and `cut -d' ' -f1-4 file` work perfectly well.

Comment: @terdon Indeed. Initially I enclosed everything for a mere and arguable stylistic choice (tough I forgot that `cut` takes filenames in the arguments). However looking at it again... I agree it doesn't look good, and after all I prefer the minimalistic approach too :). Changed. (I like that Perl `stdout` / `stderr` trick by the way)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using perl for this.
save your input in `input.txt` and run the following command:

```
cat input.txt | perl -ane 'foreach(@F){   #loop through input and split each line into an array
  chomp; #remove trailing newline
  if($_ == 0){   #print the element to STDOUT if it is "0"
    print $_," "
  }
  else{     #print the element to STDERR if it is not "0"
    print STDERR $_," "
    }
  };
  print "\n"; print STDERR "\n";' #add a newline at the end 
> x2.txt 2> x1.txt    #redirect STDOUT to x2.txt and STDERR to x1.txt
```

---

here as one-liner to copy paste:

```
cat input.txt | perl -ane 'foreach(@F){chomp;if($_ == 0){print $_," "}else{print STDERR $_," "}};print "\n"; print STDERR "\n";' > x2.txt 2> 1.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

> Just get the first numbers, which are not 0, and then just put the
>   rest in another file

In that case you can use `grep` with Perl Compatible Regex (`-P`) :

- To get the first numbers that are not zero :

  ```
  $ grep -Po '^.*\s\d+\.\d+(?=\s0\s.*)' file.txt 
  1140.271257 0.002288454025 0.002763420728 0.004142512599
  1479.704769 0.00146621631 0.003190634646 0.003672029231
  1663.276205 0.003379552854 0.04643209167 0.0539399155
  ```

  - `^.*\s\d+\.\d+` will get our desired portion
  - `(?=\s0\s.*)` is a zero width positive lookahead pattern ensuring that we have the starting of zeros after our desired postion

  To save it as `filex1.txt` :

  ```
  grep -Po '^.*\s\d+\.\d+(?=\s0\s.*)' file.txt >filex1.txt
  ```
- To get the rest i.e. zeros :

  ```
  $ grep -Po '\s\d+\.\d+\s\K0\s.*' file.txt 
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  ```

  - `\s\d+\.\d+\s` will make sure that we have a non-zero entry prior to our desired portion, `\K` will discard the match
  - `0\s.*` will get us the desired portion i.e. zero entries starting from first one

  To save it as `filex2.txt` :

  ```
  grep -Po '\s\d+\.\d+\s\K0\s.*' file.txt >filex2.txt
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using Perl:

```
perl -lne '/(.*?)\s(0\s.*)/; print "$1"; print STDERR "$2"' file > filex1 2> filex2
```

The regular expression will match everything up to the 1st `0` surrounded by whitespace and then everything from that 0 to the end of the line. The parentheses capture those two groups as `$1` and `$2` respectively. The `-l` turns on automatic trailing newline removal (`chomp`) and adds a `\n` to each `print` call. So, we print `$1` to standard output and `$2` to standard error and then redirect each to a different file.

Since this is Perl, there's more than one way to do it. This is the same idea as Wayne_Yux's answer but simplified:

```
perl -lane '@A=grep{$_==0}@F; @B=grep{$_!=0}@F;print STDERR "@A"; print "@B"' file > filex1 2>filex2
```

---

Alternatively, a simpler `grep -P`:

```
grep -oP '^.+?(?=\s0\s)' file > filex1
grep -oP ' \K0 .*' file > filex2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming once you get a `0` all the rest of fields are like this, you can say:

```
awk -v FS=" 0 " '{print $1 > "f1"; gsub($1 " ",""); print > "f2"}' file
```

This sets the field separator to the string `0` and prints the first field (that is, up to the first `0`) into the file `f1`. Then, it removes this first field from the original line and prints its result into the file `f2`.